# How to use a key's value for another key's value in yaml?

Tags: python, yaml

I am working on reading parameters from a yaml file, and I want to use a value to produce another value. For example, I need the following parameters a and b, and b uses the value of a.

```py
A:
    a: 10
    b: a * 10
B:
    ......
```

And here is how I process the file:

```py
from ruamel.yaml import safe_load, YAMLError

with open(yaml_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as hp:
    try:
        yaml_hparams = safe_load(hp)
        for _, V in yaml_hparams.items():
            for k, v in V.items():
                hparams[k] = v
    except YAMLError:
        print(YAMLError)
```

Obviously this gives a string of "a * 10" to b's value. How can I give a * 10, i.e. 100, to b?

Comment: What you want is called "interpolation of values"". The `configparser` model supports it using a [special syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values). You could implement something similar yourself. One hacky way to do that would be to convert the ymal data into standard [INI file structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure) internally in memory and then parse that with `configparser` (assuming you can change how other variables are being referenced — e.g. `b: %(a) * 10`).

Comment: You could also probably do this using Python built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function to evaluate the value expressions (assuming they use a Python-compatible syntax). However using that function may pose a security issue depending on the source of the files you want to parse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I want to keep the yaml file for the parameters, so I guess `configparser` cannot work for it? And I tried `eval()` but it cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple *proof of concept* to show the feasibility of using the built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function to do it, as I suggested in one of my comments. As such, it has some limitations such as not being able to handle "forward references", but I think many of those could be overcome, if required.

```
import json
from ruamel.yaml import safe_load, YAMLError


yaml_file = 'test_refs.yaml'

hparams = {}
with open(yaml_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as hp:
    try:
        yaml_hparams = safe_load(hp)
        for _, V in yaml_hparams.items():
            for k, v in V.items():
                hparams[k] = v
    except YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

print('Before:')
print(json.dumps(hparams, indent=4))   # Pretty-print result.

# Interpolate values with eval()
hparams['__builtins__'] = None  # Prevents access to built-ins.

for key, value in list(hparams.items()):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        try:
            hparams[key] = eval(value, hparams)
        except (NameError, TypeError):
            pass  # Possible forward-reference, ignore.

del hparams['__builtins__']  # No longer needed.

print()
print('After:')
print(json.dumps(hparams, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with YAML. YAML is a language for data serialization, it is not a programming language.

You have multiple options. One is to use a templating language like Jinja to preprocess your YAML and calculate the value. Preprocessing YAML with Jinja is done in tools like Ansible and SaltStack, so it is a rather common practice. However, be aware that Jinja does not understand the structure of YAML and you need to be careful about whitespace.

Example:

```
{% set val = 10 %}
A:
    a: {{ val }}
    b: {{ val * 10 }}
```

Obviously, you will need to call Jinja on the input before you load the YAML then.

---

Another option is to use YAML tags to tell your code how to post-process the values, and implement it there:

```
A:
    a: &val 10
    b: !prod [*val, 10]
```

Code would be something like

```
from ruamel.yaml import safe_load, SafeLoader, YAMLError
import functools

def prod_constructor(loader, node):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, loader.construct_sequence(node))

SafeLoader.add_constructor(u'!prod', prod_constructor)

with open(yaml_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as hp:
try:
    yaml_hparams = safe_load(hp)
    for _, V in yaml_hparams.items():
        for k, v in V.items():
            hparams[k] = v
except YAMLError:
    print(YAMLError)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer~ When trying the second method, an error occurred: 

`TypeError: prod_constructor() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Interesting. I tested this code with pyyaml and it worked; the ruamel docs did not mention anything about an API incompatibility here so I assumed it works there as well. A quick look at the ruamel source made it look like it *should* work; perhaps the best thing here would be opening an issue with ruamel about the error.

Comment: Yeah maybe due to version issue. Thanks for the help!